# Meaning of 'in pursuit'

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

What's the meaning of 'in pursuit' here?

> They were kicked out of the bar into town with burly men in pursuit.

Is it that the men had the aim of pursuing them, or that they were engaged in the activity of pursuing?

Comment: Also, what is the meaning of "with" here? Is it used to give accompanying detail, or to indicate association?

Comment: The interpretation of the sentence hinges on how you understand the word "with", so moving your comment to the original question would improve your question by narrowing the focus to one specific aspect

Comment: By the way, the sentence has some idiomatically odd combinations. "They were kicked out of the bar into town." "Kicked out [of a building]" usually means "forced to leave the building." It wouldn't normally take "into ___" unless we mean "kick" literally: "He kicked the ball out of the stadium and into the parking lot." Making this usage clearer would probably help clarify the "with." Maybe there's another verb missing? "They were kicked out of the bar and ran into town with burly men in pursuit"?

Comment: I have posted my question regarding the meaning of 'with' as its own question, which may be found here: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310246/meaning-of-with

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you've been confused by [definitions like this one](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20pursuit%20of), which talks about "in order to achieve something," but note that that's a different phrase, *in pursuit **of***. "In pursuit" simply means "engaged in the activity of pursuing."

Comment: What about 'with'? What does that mean here? As in, is it used to give accompanying detail, for e.g.?

Comment: @Eric That's a complicated one. Actually, even though it's the same passage, please ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of the sentence is ambiguous, but there's an obvious choice for the writer's intent.

The sentence could mean:

> 1. "They" and the burly men were both kicked out of the bar together ("with" indicates association) while they were all in pursuit (of something/someone else)
> 2. "They" and the burly men were both kicked out of the bar together ("with" indicates association) while the burly men (only) were in pursuit (of something/someone else)
> 3. "They got kicked out of the bar, and the burly men were in pursuit of "them" ("with" gives an accompanying detail).

The clear choice is 3 because the other two are semantically odd by not mentioning the object of the pursuit.

Comment: @Eric Note, we don't have to, but we *could* add a comma before "with," which would help rule out other interpretations. I still suggest you open a second question about the "with," because it's complicated. The dictionary entry for "with" is very long; it has many distinct uses. This one is about a state, like "He came to school with his shoes untied."