# Meaning of 'with'

Tags: meaning, prepositions

What's the meaning/purpose of 'with' here?

> They were chased out of town with burly men in pursuit.

Is it to give accompanying detail, or is it to indicate association (i.e. that the burly men *and* the men kicked out of the bar went into town)

Comment: Since the sentence has some flaws that don't matter to the question, could I suggest another version like "They were chased out of town with burly men in pursuit"?

Comment: @AndyBonner, thank you for your suggestion; I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: it means "they men were being chased out and burly men were in pursuit" so the event of "men being chased out" was happening **WITH** the event of "burly men pursuing."

Comment: @EliHarold. Your interpretation, it would seem, is based on the comitative meaning of 'with', which indicates accompaniment/association. However, what about the interpretation that Andy Bonner has provided, according to which 'with' is used to give accompanying detail?

Comment: @Eric I think we are talking about the same thing here, "accompaniment/association" includes "accompaniment of detail."

Comment: @EliHarold I agree that we're probably talking about the same usage in different words, but I wouldn't call it so much "with the event of" as "with the quality of." The fact that "pursuit" is a participle of a verb doesn't really affect the "with"; it's the same "with" as "they left with their hats in their hands."

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the clarification, @EliHarold.

Comment: @AndyBonner I agree, I was just trying to frame an example that might allow for easy understanding.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see by [this Merriam-Webster entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/with), English uses *with* in many, many distinct ways. It could suggest possession ("The man with one red shoe"), association ("He went to lunch with her"), or many other things.

You're closest to the mark with "give accompanying detail." In this case, "with burly men in pursuit" is an adverbial phrase describing how they were chased. Similar sentences might be "He came to school with his shoes untied" or "He went to bed with pleasant thoughts in his head." It describes a state. I think the most applicable entry from the long dictionary page is:

> 7 b: —used as a function word to indicate an attendant fact or circumstance
> // stood there *with* his hat on

Comment: The interpretation you provide here was the one I originally thought was correct in the given context.